# grep in ifelse for a vector of values

Tags: r, if-statement

I have the following dataframe:

```
data <- data.frame(MOBILE_NUMBER = c(
          "999/277-135",        
          "075-788-476",        
          "078-388-607",        
          "077/969-557",        
          "076/423-130"))
```

And I want to create a boolean variable if the first 7 characters in the string match one of the values in the following vector:

```
list_values <- c("071", "072", "073", "074", "075", "076", "077", "078", "079")
```

I can pull the values with the following grep code:

```
grep(paste(list_values,collapse="|"), 
                     data$MOBILE_NUMBER, value=TRUE))
```

But i'm  not sure how to put this in a ifelse statement, and especially how to text it only on the first 7 elements of the string.

Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `substr` to get the substring of 1st 7 chararacters, apply the `grepl` on it and convert it to binary (if needed) using `as.integer`

```
as.integer(grepl(paste(list_values,collapse="|"), substr(data[[1]], 1, 7)))
```